# Does Allure supports Bitbucket Pipelines?

Tags: selenium, gradle, allure, bitbucket-pipelines

Is it possible to integrate Allure [test reporting tool] into Atlassian Bitbucket Pipelines CI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you have to implement a lot manually. Our setup is:

- Tests save results
- allure-commandline generates report
- Generated report is published in a shared bucket on S3
- A link to the report is sent in email

Currently working on storing Allure history.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using bitbucket pages and it works fine
please refer to --> https://www.w3schools.com/git/git_remote_pages.asp?remote=bitbucket

Basically allure report starts a webserver to open the report, and when you host the allure reports using bitbucket pages, then bitbucket acts as a server and opens the report.

create a repo as below

[Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gQZu.png)

Once the allure generates the "allure-report" - push the entire folder to this repository

Now on your repository, navigate to allure-report folder where index.html is placed.

copy the breadcrumbs and open the link in new tab

[image]

[image]

[image: Opens the report]

In our project, we automatatically post the reports by creating the necessary git steps on the deployment yaml file. So whenever the test runs it pushes the report to this repository